# How do I run my PL/SQL on APEX 4.0 every 2 minutes?

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

I have a simple PL/SQL code that fetches some data from my tables, computes some value and outputs it to my APEX UI.

Consider a simple code like : 
    declare
    cr number;
    Begin
    select sum(testing) into cr from sample;
    htp.p(cr);
    end;

The output would be like "40" which should change to "new_value" after 2 minutes.
I can't refresh/reload the entire page as there is a lot of code that should not be refreshed on the same page.How do I run the query again every 2 minutes or refresh the output on the screen in APEX? 
I considered a couple of options but nothing seems to work : 
1. Introduce a loop and a sleep() but sleep() doesn't work for APEX.
2. Embed javascript (setInterval) in my PL/SQL code, which is again not getting parsed correctly. 
Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Apex timer plugin to reload your page at set intervals. In the page load proces you can recalculate the values you need.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/apex/application-express/apex-plug-ins-182042.html

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to set your page to Auto Refresh. Basically in your page header you have something like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="&F100_REFRESH_INTERVAL.">
```

And your application has an item `F100_REFRESH_INTERVAL` which is defaulted to 120.

http://jeffkemponoracle.com/2006/10/25/apex-tip-page-auto-refresh/

Comment: Thanks a lot! Although I was able to achieve the result with Apex timer plugin, will give this a try.. If I am correct, it this taking values of time from the list of values of F100_REFRESH_INTERVAL and performing a refresh according to it?

Comment: that's right - and you can add an item to the page if you want so that the user can change the refresh interval if they want.